# Unable to implement IQueryDesigner for SSRS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have a custom SSRS Data Processing Extension and an associated custom query designer that was created for SSRS 2008 R2. I am attempting to get this to work with SSRS 2012.

My custom query designer implements the IQueryDesigner interface found in Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.dll. This DLL can be found in the Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2012 folder, depending on which version of the BI tools are installed.
e.g. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies" for Visual Studio 2012.

In SSRS 2012 the Data Processing Extension works fine but the query designer does not.

It seems that although SSRS 2012 extensions require .NET 3.5, the IQueryDesigner interface requires .NET 4.

For example, if I create a Class Library project with a Target Framework of ".NET Framework 3.5", then reference Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.dll, I am unable to build.
If I change the Target Framework to ".NET Framework 4" I can then build, but the resulting DLL does not work in SSRS 2012.
Does anyone have ideas what I might be doing wrong? Or perhaps implementing IQueryDesigner simply no longer works as of SSRS 2012?

UPDATE: I resolved this issue by creating two DLLs. The first implements the Data Processing Extension and is built using .NET 3.5.  The second implements the IQueryDesigner interface and is built using .NET 4.